# Do I ask my question, which is related to MATLAB software problems, on Stack Overflow or in Super User?

Tags: support, scope

I have a question which is related to the MATLAB  environment, but it doesn't have anything to do with programming (some features aren't working correctly).

MATLAB is dedicated to programming and simulation, and that's why I'm confused.

Comment: Much better to ask here before asking on SO. 1+ for your due diligence.

Comment: sorry its features, thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do you have the source code available to you, to see and possibly modify? If so, then Stack Overflow is an appropriate place to ask, since you're obviously acting as a programmer.

Are you using the MATLAB environment, even though you aren't doing any actual programming? If so, then Stack Overflow is an appropriate place to ask, since MATLAB is a tool commonly used by programmers, making it on-topic here.

If you're just running some sort of packaged binary, without access to any of the internals, then Stack Overflow is **not** an appropriate place to ask. We cannot provide help with every application. Super User *may* be an appropriate place to ask in these cases, but probably won't be able to provide very good help for custom-built, one-off applications.

We'd need more details about the specific question to be able to render a definite decision.